# order of operations when a Service gets shut down

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm writing a Service that uses an AsyncTask to do some network operations. Let's say the doInBackground of the AsyncTask is taking a very long time, and while that's happening, resources get low and the operating system is shutting down the Service.

When does the AsyncTask get killed? Will the AsyncTask still be running when onDestroy is called, or will it happen afterwards, or am I responsible for shutting down the AsyncTask? I'm trying to make sure I do not have race conditions between the code in my onDestroy and the code in my doInBackground.

Comment: Just curious but why are you using an AsyncTask in a Service?

Comment: The service is running in the same process as the main application, so I believe in that case I need to use an AsyncTask so the service's network access doesn't block the main ui thread.

Comment: a Service is already running on its own thread. AsyncTasks are meant for Activitys

Comment: Services do *not* already run on their own thread. From the android.app.Service docs: "A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AsyncTask will continue running until either you cancel it or the system destroys the process hosting it. The system doesn't know, per se, about your AsyncTask so its not going to do anything about it when shutting down the Service, it certainly doesn't know the Service created the AsyncTask.

Its very likely that after onDestroy is called that the application's process will be destroyed as well and so will the AsyncTask. However, the safest policy is to be proactive and cancel the AsyncTask in onDestroy.

A perhaps interesting side note is that requests queued for processing will be lost if the process dies before they are processed. As such, any operations sent to an AsyncTask that *must* be completed need to be written to a persistent task log so they can be reissued if not completed.